# Hooks not getting executed in protractor cucumber

Tags: automated-testing, javascript, protractor, cucumber, angular

I new to protractor, and trying to implement hooks. But the hooks are not getting executed.
Following is my code:
**Hook.js**:

```
const {
    Before
} = require('cucumber');

const {AfterAll} = require('cucumber');

module.exports = function () {
    
   Before(function () {
        browser.manage().window().maximize();
       /// await browser.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        
    });

    AfterAll(async function () {
        return driver.quit();
    });
}
```

I have also added the path in config.js:
[image]

Do I need to give its path in spec.js as well?

Comment: Compare what you've written to https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/hooks.md. Just requiring your hook file doesn't *do* anything, because the function isn't executed. Also you can't have two require keys in one object, the value is an array so you can have multiple entries there.

Comment: The issue is now resolved. After removing module.exports = function() from hooks.js,it worked fine.

Comment: I'd suggest deleting this then

Answer (score 1):

Try to understand what the code does:

```
const {
    Before
} = require('cucumber');

const {AfterAll} = require('cucumber');

module.exports = function () {
    
   Before(function () {
        browser.manage().window().maximize();
       /// await browser.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        
    });

    AfterAll(async function () {
        return driver.quit();
    });
}
```

Here you creates a function but never calls the function.

you can make it work in three ways:

**First Approach: Call the function and pass the object to module.exports**

```
const {
    Before
} = require('cucumber');

const {AfterAll} = require('cucumber');

//store function to a variable
let hooks = function () {
    
   Before(function () {
        browser.manage().window().maximize();
       /// await browser.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        
    });

    AfterAll(async function () {
        return driver.quit();
    });
}

//call the function and pass it to module.exports
module.exports = hooks();
```

**Second Approach: Create self-invoking function**

```
const {
    Before
} = require('cucumber');

const {AfterAll} = require('cucumber');

module.exports = (function () {
    
   Before(function () {
        browser.manage().window().maximize();
       /// await browser.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        
    });

    AfterAll(async function () {
        return driver.quit();
    });
})();
```

**Third Approach: create an object using object literal instead of creating a function and calling it ( This what you have done as the fix )**

```
const {
    Before
} = require('cucumber');

const {AfterAll} = require('cucumber');

module.exports = {
    
   Before(function () {
        browser.manage().window().maximize();
       /// await browser.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        
    });

    AfterAll(async function () {
        return driver.quit();
    });
};
```